# Assigned anonymous function within assigned anonymous function

Tags: php

I do an experiment that trying to call the anonymous function within anonymous function, but it doesn't work and getting some errors :

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: print -- at line 10
E_ERROR : type 1 -- Function name must be a string -- at line 10
```

Anyone can tell me the reason?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

   $print = function($key, $val){
      return 'The key: ' . $key . ', and value: ' . $val . '<br />';
   };

   $output = function($datas, $done_action){
      foreach($datas as $key => $val){
        echo $print($key, $val);
      }

      $done_action();
   };

   $elem1 = array('Name' => 'Aldi', 'Phone' => '087770958005', 'Address' => 'Bogor');
   $output($elem1, function(){
      echo '<br />Foreach function was ended!';
   });

?>
```

Comment: anonymous function comes from php 5.3, check your php version.

Comment: @xdazz my php version is already support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the [use](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-186) keyword to use external variables inside of a closure. Your code should be:

```
<?php

$print = function($key, $val){
  return 'The key: ' . $key . ', and value: ' . $val . '<br />';
};

$output = function($datas, $done_action) use ($print) {
  foreach($datas as $key => $val){
    echo $print($key, $val);
  }

  $done_action();
};

$elem1 = array('Name' => 'Aldi', 'Phone' => '087770958005', 'Address' => 'Bogor');
$output($elem1, function(){
  echo '<br />Foreach function was ended!';
});
```

Runs without error on my php-5.3.10.